# MySQL - Are "NOT NULL" constraints needed for primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

is it necessary to declare "NOT NULL" constraints for primary keys in the MySQL database?  A primary key cannot have NULL values because it auto_increments anyway and automatically fills the field record. So am I correct in saying this mean I can remove the "NOT NULL" constraint for my primary keys?

Comment: Having them on the column _does not hurt_ and when reading the table definition makes things _explicit_. If, in the future, you change the primary key constraint, you would still have the `NOT NULL` constraint around.

Comment: You do have two concepts intertwined which you shouldn't have. A primary key need not be an auto incrementing column, nor (if a table has one) must an auto incrementing column be the primary key. Just because they *tend* to be used together does not mean that they are the same thing.

Answer (score 21):

*(As you've tagged your question `mysql`.)* In MySQL, you don't have to do it explicitly. From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html#id879566):

> A `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index where all key columns must be defined as `NOT NULL`. If they are not explicitly declared as `NOT NULL`, MySQL declares them so implicitly (and silently).

Of course, just because you don't *have* to doesn't mean you might not want to for clarity, etc.

Comment: Not only it declares the PK columns as `NOT NULL`, it evens overrides/modifies them to `NOT NULL` if they have been declared as `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no
You can remove "Not null", that won't remove the constraint though. Personally I'd leave them in, you gain nothing worthwhile from taking them out.

Comment: No, you can't. If a column is part of the Primary Key, the Not Null constraint cannot be changed to Null.

Comment: @ypercube He didn't say "change to NULL", he said "remove NOT NULL". Just because NOT NULL is not in the DDL text doesn't mean it's not in force.

Comment: @Branko: If he meant "remove the wording "NOT NULL" from the definition", yeah, I agree. Reading again, you are right, that's probably what was meant.

Comment: So yes what I am saying is I do not need to type in NOT NULL for the primary keys because NOT NULL is already added by MySQL so - `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,     becomes `id` int(11) auto_increment,

Comment: No probably about it. Type it in anyway, I mean it's not that much of an effort is it. And then if say you want to use some other dbms, or change the primary key, you won't be having doh moment. I loathe terseness as a language option, it's for people too clever to be allowed to work in the real world, they'll be abbreviating it to nN next....

Answer (score 0):

Primary key must not include nullable columns. `auto_increment` is not a check constraint, (it is rather a default constraint) , so you cannot remove `not null` from definition of the column that is part of primary key regardless of presence of `auto_increment`. You don't have to type `not null` while creating the table for primary key in mysql, because the engine adds this constraint automatically.

Answer (score 0):

WE need not declare explicitly the column as not null because Primary key constraint makes the column NOT NULL. I have checked in Oracle.