# Can prime attributes have null values?

Tags: database, relational-database, primary-key, candidate-key

I understand that a candidate key can not have NULL values. But a candidate key can itself be a combination of many attributes which are called prime attributes. Can these prime attributes have NULL as a value?

Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Are "NOT NULL" constraints needed for primary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462918/mysql-are-not-null-constraints-needed-for-primary-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Prime attribute An attribute which appears as an attribute for some
>   candidate key. (It needn't be the primary key, or even any key of
>   interest.)

[Schemas and keys](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/Csc598.073/notes/reldb.html)

Prime attributes are part of a candidate key. A candidate key, as the name suggests, is a candidate for primary key. That means, a candidate key *can* become a primary key, if required.

Now if you recall, any primary key cannot be null. So, by definition, a prime attribute cannot be null. If it is null, it ceases to be a prime attribute.

Here is an explanation.

If you have a composite candidate key lets say

```
CK1(P1, P2)
```

P1 and P2 are a prime attributes. You can set P1 or P2 as null, because there is no constraint on prime attributes other than those of primary key attributes.

So,

```
CK1(P1, P2=null)
```

Now, CK1 cannot be a primary key, hence is no more a candidate key and hence, P2 is no more a prime attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on the database you use.

For example, you don't have to do it explicitly in MySQL. This is defined in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html#id879566):

> A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined
>   as NOT NULL. If they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL
>   declares them so implicitly (and silently).